# Duvidas sobre qual infra escolher

Tags: amazon-aws, cloud

Como faria para colocar uma API no ar junto com um front-end?

Exemplo:

Tenho uma aplicação em Angular JS Uma SPA e ela tem uma API que necessita de um banco de dados, então como eu faria? Criaria uma instancia EC2 e um roteamento?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português!  Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Answer (score 2):

Se você for realmente usar a AWS, te sugiro o seguinte:

Suba uma instância que faça parte do [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/free/), assim você tem um ano de testes (se já não tiver usado) e coloque sua aplicação. Lembre-se de atualizar o `security group` da instância para permitir acesso somente às portas necessárias e também não permita acesso à porta 22 de qualquer fonte, coloque seu IP atual.

Ainda sobre a instância, ela já vai ter um IP público associado mas esse IP vai mudar se a máquina for desligada, se ela for reiniciada o IP continua o mesmo. Se quiser ter um IP público fixo, é preciso usar o [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

Para o banco de dados você pode usar o [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/) mas é bem caro e você pode resolver essa situação colocando o seu banco em uma outra instância ou até na mesma instância da sua aplicação, o que não recomendo. A vantagem de se usar o RDS e motivo do seu alto custo é que a Amazon fica responsável por gerar backups e manter o seu banco sempre atualizado, tendo o mínimo de envolvimento da sua parte além de te dar opção de [Multi A-Z](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/details/multi-az/) aonde você vai ter o seu banco disponível em zonas diferentes, te dando mais segurança.

Você pode criar um domínio e configurar para que ele aponte para o IP público da sua máquina.

Caso você tenha mais de uma instância rodando sua aplicação, você pode criar um [Elastic Load Balancer (ELB)](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/elasticloadbalancing/), ele vai ter um DNS e você pode usar ele mas não pode usar os IPs pois eles alteram.

Comment: Amigo, muitíssimo obrigado, mas é quanto ao DNS? Normalmente fica s3.aws.... teria como colocar o meu próprio DNS lá? Como daria?

Comment: Desculpe a demora pra responder mas você consegue configurar isso pelo próprio administrador do seu domínio, você vai fazer um redirecionamento, toda vez que bater no seu domínio ele vai ser enviado par ao s3.aws

Answer (score 1):

Poderia ser mais específico? O banco de dados você precisa hospedar também, ou só acessar externo?

Se o site for "estático", ou seja, só com Javascript e afins, não precisa de uma instância EC2 para hospedar, pode deixar no S3 e tornar público.

Se for "dinâmico", e precisa de algum servidor processando a resposta aos clientes, então sim use uma instância EC2 e instale o que for necessário rodar nela.